# .htaccess rewrite to redirect xyz.com to abc.com/subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'd like to 301 redirect my current domain to new subdirectory in different domain (moving my blogs to one new domain and using Multisite wordpress installation with subdirectories).

`xyz.com` to `abc.com/subdirectory` and this inclode the `www.xyz.com` also
Any idea what the .htaccess should be?

Answer (score 0):

try this, (if you want `.htaccess` solution)

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Place this to `xyz.com/.htaccess`

Other solution, You can also addn `CNAME` record to your DNS setting, (domain hosting panel).

e.g of `CNAME` Record according to your need.

```
| Name/Host/Alias          | Record Type     |   Value/Answer/Destination  |

| *  (to redirect all)     | CNAME           |   www.abc.com/subdirectory  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[check this for more information on CNAME record](http://www.networking4all.com/en/support/domain+names/dns/cname-records/)

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in `xyz.com`'s root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com/subdirectory%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: That's mean I don't need to use my old url in the .htaccess file as I'm placing the code on it root, right?

Comment: Another thing I'm redirecting it to abc.com/subdirectory without www. so just I remove the www. from your code?

Comment: yes just removed `www` from target URI. See updated code and let me know how it goes.